# c++ bitset questions

Tags: c++

I want to ask two C++ bitset questions.

(1) How to create a bitset with a specified length from a function argument? I mean, for example, I have a function

```
void f(int n)
```

And inside `f`, I need to create `bitset<n> bs;` Is this something doable?

(2) How to copy part of a bitset `bs` to form a new bitset? For example, given `starting index i1` and `ending index i2` where `i1`>=`i2`, I need to form a new bitset by copying those bits in `bs` from the least `i2`th significant bit exclusive to the least `i1`th significant bit inclusive (just to conform with `STL` convention).

Thank you.

Comment: These are not the <strike>droids</strike>bitsets you want. Amazingly enough, you're looking for `vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Not doable with `std::bitset`, because the size needs to be a compile-time constant (integral constant expression). You can use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), or, alternatively, `std::vector<bool>` or `std::vector<char>`

(2) `std::bitset` does not a special constructor for what you're looking for. You will need to write an explicit loop. All the other options listed in (1), however, have a constructor taking two iterators.

Comment: if I use `std::vector<bool> `, how to conveniently convert it to long, as bitset's `to_ulong()` does?

Comment: @littleEinstein: Use `boost::dynamic_bitset`. It has the `to_ulong` function. If you use vector, you'll have to implement the functionality yourself

Comment: @littleEinstein Use `std::accumulate` with `unsigned long leftShiftAdd(unsigned long total, bool bit) { total << 1; if(bit) total |= 1; return total; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use boost? If so then boost::dynamic_bitset might be what you need. If not then `std::vector<bool>` might work, internally it's stored as a bitset rather than a vector of bools, and you should be able to use std::copy to copy your ranges of bits.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: there is [Boost.Dynamic Bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) which is exactly what you want.

For the second question: here I'd simply to a `(bs >> i2) & ~bitset(i1 - i2)`.